# how to change variable based on selector in sass

Tags: css, sass, vuejs2, themes, node-sass

I want to toggle theme in my project and i have used sass as my css preprocessor. I have declared all the variables for a theme and i want to change the values for the declared variable based on the selector.
My current Code:

```
$nightSelector: '.night';
$daySelector: '.day';

#{$nightSelector} {
    $headerBgColor: #333;
}
#{$daySelector} {
    $headerBgColor: #f3f4f8;
}
header {
    background: $headerBgColor;
}
```

Getting compilation error with $headerBgColor undefined. 
Is there any right way to do this? Or, provide any solution to accomplish it. I'm vue as my frontend framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this may be a scope issue. Aren't all variables declared within selectors locally scoped?

Comment: Oh!!Got it..is there any other method to achieve it

Comment: I haven't used sass in quite some time, but isn't it something simple like declaring the variable outside the selectors first, then simply updating its value through the selectors. Ex: below `$nightSelector: '.night;'` and `$daySelector: '.day';`, add `$headerBgColor: null;`. --- Or is it `nil`? Anyway, I think it's something like that.

Answer (score 1):

SCSS variables are static (used to produce CSS output) why you can't use them to dynamically change values depending on context (that's a job for CSS variables).

**Example 1 – SCSS variables only**

**SCSS**

```
$nightSelector: '.night';
$daySelector  : '.day';

header {
    #{$nightSelector} &,
    &#{$nightSelector} { background: #333; }

    #{$daySelector} &, 
    &#{$daySelector} { background: #f3f4f8; }

}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.night header, header.night {
  background: #333;
}
.day header, header.day {
  background: #f3f4f8;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="night">Lorem</header>
<header class="day">Lorem</header>

<body class="night">
  <header>Lorem</header>
</body>

<body class="day">
   <header>Lorem</header>
</body>
```

**Example 2 – SCSS + CSS variables**

**SCSS**

```
$nightSelector: '.night';
$daySelector: '.day';

#{$nightSelector} {
    --header-bg-color: #333;
}
#{$daySelector} {
    --header-bg-color: #f3f4f8;
}
header {
    background: var(--header-bg-color);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.night {
    --header-bg-color: #333;
}
.day {
    --header-bg-color: #333;
}
header {
    background: var(--header-bg-color);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="night">Lorem</header>
<header class="day">Lorem</header>

<body class="night">
  <header>Lorem</header>
</body>

<body class="day">
   <header>Lorem</header>
</body>
```